# Are donations typically expected from the person receiving an aliyah?

Tags: synagogue, tzedakah-charity, torah-service, orthodox, social-convention

Is it the normal practice of Orthodox shuls to expect a donation from a person who received an aliyah, even if there is no formal system of reminding or requiring the person to give a donation?

Comment: From my experience, it depends. My current synagogue (Modern Orthodox with a middle to upper income congregation) does not. My previous synagogue (Modern Orthodox with a Lubavitsh rabbi and a lower to moderate income congregation) did. At one point some worshipers at my previous synagogue requested that they not be asked for tzadikah when receiving an aliyah to avoid embarrassment. If I recall correctly, the shul stopped asking for money for a short time then resumed. For the High Holy Days, I remember people actually bidding for aliyot

Comment: It really depends on the shul. Just see what everyone else is doing. In some shuls, they bid on the aliyot. Some shuls require above $100 donations per aliyah. Others require $18 donations.

Comment: I have heard from the family of R' Teitz (mara d'atra, Elizabeth, NJ) that historically it was not uncommon to bid on aliyot, whether with mitzvot or currency, and that it was even permissible on shabbat. It is now very uncommon, but the schul where I davened last Yom Kippur did this for maftir Yonah.

Comment: If it's a bar mitzvah boy or an ufruf  (aliya on shabbos before wedding) a lot of places ask for donations. For Rosh Hashana and mainly Yom Kippur, a lot of places sell or auction aliyos. As for other times, most shuls don't charge, although there are a few that do.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the Shuls that are expecting a donation make a special Mi Shebeirach after the Mi Shebeirach of the Aliya. Ultimately those that do not want to or can not afford to donate say Tziva Lvarcham.